# Linearly recursive list-difference function in Common Lisp

Tags: algorithm, recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I was going through [this](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CC/310/pwfong/Lisp/1/tutorial1.html) tutorial for fun, and got stuck on the very last thing he says, "Exercise: Give a linearly recursive implementation of union and difference." (for a list)

Union, no sweat.

Difference, sweat.

An attempt looks like this. . .

```
(defun list-diff (L1 L2)
  (cond
    ((null L1) L2) 
    ((null (member (first L1) L2)) (cons (first L1) (list-diff (rest L1) L2)))
    (t (list-diff (rest L1) L2))
  )
)
```

Now, that returns all the elements that are in L1 that aren't in L2, but it just returns all of L2 (obviously). Similarly, if I change the L2 in line 3 to "nil", then it just returns all of L1 that aren't in L2, but none of L2.

My attempts at work-arounds don't look recursive, and when they are, I end up getting stack-overflows (like if I try calling (list-diff L2 L1) somewhere).

Any of his other exercises, such as list-intersection, only require running through the elements of L1. Here, I want to strike the crucial elements from L2, or run (list-diff L2 L1) and then union the results from both, but that's not really linearly-recursive anymore.

Thoughts?

(not homework, really. I just thought I'd try to look at some LISP for fun.)

EDIT: a function that does this properly, based on the responses is:

```
(defun list-diff (L1 L2)
  (cond
    ((null L1) nil)
    ((null (member (first L1) L2)) (cons (first L1) (list-diff (rest L1) L2)))
    (t (list-diff (rest L1) L2))
  )
)
```

Comment: Well, yeah, just return l1 is the first clause.

Comment: Style: write the test in the second clause without the call to null and swap the consequence part of the second and third clause. Simplifies the code a bit.

Comment: Style: don't use C formatting. Put the parentheses behind the end of the function. Use automatic indentation, parentheses highlighting, etc. to get the code structure right.

Comment: Rainer -- thanks. Perhaps you could post an answer with your changes made so that I could see them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [set difference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetDifference.html) operation L1 \ L2 is defined as all elements e such that e is in L1 but e not in L2.  So it looks to me like your second attempt is actually correct:

> Similarly, if I change the L2 in line
>   3 to "nil", then it just returns all
>   of L1 that aren't in L2, but none of
>   L2.

It looks like you're trying to compute the [symmetric difference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SymmetricDifference.html), although it isn't clear to me that this is what the exercise requests.

If you want to be clever about it, you can probably pass a third list into the function to serve as an accumulator.  When L1 has elements, push the first element into the accumulator (and call recursively) when `(null (member (first L1) L2))`.  When L1 is null, check the elements of L2 against the accumulator list, doing the same thing.  When L1 and L2 are null, return the accumulator list.

Comment: Oh, all right. I had my definition of set-difference wrong, then. I was thinking of symmetric difference.

Yes, my second version does it properly. I had thought about using accumulators, but that hadn't been introduced by the time he gave that exercise.

Answer (score 4):

In Lisp this is the definition of 'set difference':

```
set-difference list1 list2 &key (test #'eql) test-not (key #'identity)
   Function
   Returns a list of elements of list1 that do not appear in list2.
```

That's your modified implementation:

```
(defun list-diff (L1 L2)
  (cond
    ((null L1) L1)
    ((member (first L1) L2) (list-diff (rest L1) L2))
    (t (cons (first l1) (list-diff (rest l1) l2)))))
```